# How to Write exceptions into Log file...?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have using Spring MVC...

After dispatcher servlet loading, i am getting exception. I need to write that exception into log file...

I getting error... The TCP/IP connection to the host 192.168.100.178, port 1433 has failed. Error: "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall."

I could not write into Log file…

Can anyone help?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could make your own custom exception which is thrown once you catch all TCP/IP connection exceptions. Once your custom exception is thrown you can simply write logs into a file you specify.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Log4j`

[Here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-log4j-integration-example/) is good tutorial to follow

Answer (score 0):

**Log4j 2 Configuration :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- No need to set system property "Log4jContextSelector" to any value
when using <asyncLogger> or <asyncRoot>. -->

<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
    <!-- Async Loggers will auto-flush in batches, so switch off immediateFlush. -->
        <RandomAccessFile name="RandomAccessFile" fileName="asyncWithLocation.log"
            immediateFlush="false" append="false">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d %p %class{1.} [%t] %location %m %ex%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </RandomAccessFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
    <!-- pattern layout actually uses location, so we need to include it -->
        <AsyncLogger name="com.foo.Bar" level="trace" includeLocation="true">
            <AppenderRef ref="RandomAccessFile"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
        <Root level="info" includeLocation="true">
            <AppenderRef ref="RandomAccessFile"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Above configuration taken from [Mixing Synchronous and Asynchronous Loggers](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/async.html)

You can **add Exception in log file** as :-

```
Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Your_Class_Name.class);
try {
    // do something
} catch (Exception e) {
    StringWriter stack = new StringWriter();
    e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(stack));
    logger.fatal(stack.toString());
};
```